# Separate output from function while multithreading (bash)

Tags: multithreading, bash, function

I'm trying to program a .zip password cracker (to decrypt an old .zip file from which i forgot the password) and I want to make it faster.

I think the speed limit is made by unzip (using unzip -t -P) to test the password. I thought I 
could make it faster, if I duplicate the original file and testing it with the password generators ('til now I only use seq to test numbers and generatewords to test words). My problem is, that I cannot output the numbers and "words" separately.

I tried it like this:

```
generate (){

seq 0 999999 & generatewords 5 1 a A

}

check (){

generate | while read password; do

unzip -tqqq -P $password $file &>/dev/null

if [ $? = 0 ]; then

echo -e "Password found:\n\n\"$password\"" && exit

fi

done

}
```

But logically, I only get the numbers and words mixed as output. Is there any way to seperate them and give them as argument to the next function, so it can work on more files? And if one of them gets a match, the script should exit. Can you do this in bash? Other improvements are welcome.

Sorry for my bad english and the bad formatting :/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Thank you. Didn't know/understand it in the help, but I will do it like this next time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible you can just use `$1` and run your check function from the other function

```
check (){
read password
unzip -tqqq -P $password $file &>/dev/null
if [ $? = 0 ]; then
echo "Password is a $1"
echo -e "Password found:\n\n\"$password\"" && exit
fi;}

generate (){
while true; do
seq 0 999999 | check number
generatewords 5 1 a A | check word
done;}
```

You can use `$1` in any way you want the way i did it was just a sugestion

Comment: the `exit` should exit the whole script so this neverending loop should do

Comment: useing args is a bit harder i couldn't fugure out how to do it so i just decided to use a pipe and read